# how to test push notifications with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to continously blackbox test the push part of my application.
It is no problem to trigger the push notification with jenkins. The problem is to test if the notification also got delivered correctly.

I see three possible Sollutions

1. Jenkins could somehow register with GCM and APNS as device and directly receive the push
2. There could be an simple testing app on the phone which would notify jenkins upon reception.
3. ADB (not sure about iOS) connected devices bound to jenkins.

Has anyone ever tried something like this?